# Trying to make an image rotate using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rotation

I'm working on making an image rotate, and my console tells me that there are no errors with my javascripts, but the image doesn't rotate when I mouseover. Here are the file contents:

under `myjavascripts.js`

```
   $("#image").rotate({ 
   bind: 
     { 
        mouseover : function() { 
            $(this).rotate({animateTo:180})
        },
        mouseout : function() { 
            $(this).rotate({animateTo:0})
        }
     } 

    });
```

and under my `index.erb`

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/myjavascript.js"></script>
... 
<img border="0" src="/images/transparent_drapes.jpg" alt="drapes" width="" height="" id="image">
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you doing this on document ready? Your image must be loaded for this to work, right?

Comment: @AlexShilman I'm not sure what you mean? I'm using Sinatra and have the image loaded in my images folder. Does that answer your question?

Comment: This isn't a Ruby question so I'm removing the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You  need to wrap your code in document ready, because your image has to be loaded onto the page before the events get to register. `$(function(){})` like this:

```
 $(function(){
   $("#image").rotate({ 
   bind: 
  { 
    mouseover : function() { 
        $(this).rotate({animateTo:180})
    },
    mouseout : function() { 
        $(this).rotate({animateTo:0})
    }
   } 

  });
  });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yacekayu/1/edit)**

Comment: Fantastic! It was the first part that did it (`$(function(){`), and some other modifications...

Comment: The way you responded makes me think you don't know what `$(function(){}` does. It's equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() {});`. Basically, it's an event handler that fires when the web page has finished loading in all the assets and whatnot.

Comment: @Cereal, thats exactly my point. Image is a part of the document, so when the document is ready, meaning the DOM, register the function mouseover, rotate...Which part of my answer gave you that impression?

Comment: @AlexShilman Sorry, I was responding to modulus. Your answer was great. It was his "It was the first part that did it" comment that kind of implied he didn't have a clue what it did, just that it worked.

Answer (score 3):

why using jquery while it can be done with some CSS3

CSS

```
.rotate{
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
transition-duration: 0.8s;

-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-o-transition-property: -o-transform;
transition-property: transform;

overflow:hidden;

}
```

and on hover use this

```
.rotate:hover  
{
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
-o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

Then just attach the class “rotate” with any image or text to rotate it 360 degree.

Source : http://blog.vivekv.com/rotate-image-360deg-when-mouse-hover-using-css-3.html

Comment: I am just practicing my jQuery and want to do this without CSS, but I appreciate your answer and may end up using this later.

Answer (score 1):

```
.rotate img {
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.rotate img:hover {
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
```

DEMO [Growth pages](http://growthpages.com/)